# Get ID of created OpenLayers Marker Box

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map and I create boxes with **OpenLayers.Marker.Box** like this:

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(left, bottom, right, top);
var box = new OpenLayers.Marker.Box(bounds);
boxes.addMarker(box);
```

I need to get the ID of this box to add some functionality. But when I create the box, OpenLayers automatically adds a div ID like **OpenLayersDiv135**. Is it possible to get the box ID in my javascript right after it is created or even set the ID at creation time?

EDIT:
It's as simple as **console.log(box.div.id);**

Comment: **box.div.id** is the (really simple) solution!